# Can we get the column which contains the search result in SQL server FTS search

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

I am new to FTS of SQL Server. So this might be an obvious question but i am not able to find any answer. I want to perform a search on 3 columns of a table. I can fire a query like :

SELECT docid from TBLFTS 
where CONTAINS(* , 'SearchTerm')

Now this 'SearchTerm' can be found in Column C1, C2 or C3 and i want to know in which column this search term was found. It could be in all the columns or any one or any two. Is it possible to know the column in which the search text was found?
I can create new tables for each searchable column, but that will involve lots of work and will be my last resort. 
Any help around this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like an obvious requirement but I can't see how how it could be achieved either. Could you search the columns individually and UNION the results. If you want the results in a single row you could roll them up using GROUP/MAX/CASE like this or a PIVOT.

```
; with cte as (
    SELECT docid, 'Column1' as ColumnName from TBLFTS where CONTAINS(Column1 , 'SearchTerm')
    UNION ALL
    SELECT docid, 'Column2' as ColumnName from TBLFTS where CONTAINS(Column2 , 'SearchTerm')
    UNION ALL
    SELECT docid, 'Column3' as ColumnName from TBLFTS where CONTAINS(Column3 , 'SearchTerm')
)
select
    docid,
    max(case when ColumnName = 'Column1' then 1 else 0 end) as IsInColumn1,
    max(case when ColumnName = 'Column2' then 1 else 0 end) as IsInColumn2,
    max(case when ColumnName = 'Column3' then 1 else 0 end) as IsInColumn3
from
    cte
group by
    docid
```

You should check the performance impact but I wouldn't be too surprised if the hit was negligable.

Comment: Thanks Rhys. I will try this solution. Again there will be some work to be done as I wanted the information for a particular document consolidated in a single row instead of spanning multiple rows. But this seems to be the best approach as there is no straight forward way. I will mark your solution as answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

simpler answer:

```
SELECT docid, 'Column1' AS ColumnName1, 'Column2' AS ColumnName2, 'Column3' AS ColumnName3 FROM TBLFTS WHERE CONTAINS(Column1 , 'SearchTerm') OR CONTAINS(Column2 , 'SearchTerm') OR CONTAINS(Column3 , 'SearchTerm')
```

Comment: This will not give the desired output. It will give all column names even if the search text was found only in the first column.